# An operator satisfying in a sequence of equations

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, compact-operators

Assume that $H$ is a non-separable Hilbert space. 
Let $\{\eta_n\}$ be an arbitrary sequence in $H$.

Let $\{\zeta_n\}$ be a sequence in $H$ which forms a **linearly independent** set. 
Does there exist any bounded operator $x$ in $B(H)$ satisfying in the equations  $x\zeta_n=\eta_n$ ($n=1,2,\cdots$)?

Comment: That depends on the sequences $(\zeta_n),\,(\eta_n)$. If $(\|\eta_n\|/\|\zeta_n\|)$ is not bounded, the resulting operator will not be bounded.

Comment: OK, assume that the quotient that you wrote is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where $\|\eta_n\|=\|\zeta_n\|=1$ for all $n$, but $T$ is unbounded.

Let $\zeta_n$ be any orthonormal sequence, and define
$$
\eta_n=\frac{\zeta_1+\zeta_{n+1}}{\sqrt2}.
$$
Then $\|\eta_n\|=\|\zeta_n\|=1$ for all $n$.

Now consider 
$$
\xi_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n \zeta_k.
$$
Then $\|\xi_n\|=1$. If $T\zeta_n=\eta_n$ for all $n$ and $T$ is linear, then 
\begin{align}
\|T\xi_n\|^2&=\left\|\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n T\zeta_k \right\|^2
=\left\|\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}\sum_{k=1}^n{\zeta_1+\zeta_{k+1}} \right\|^2\\ \ \\
&=\left\|\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}\left({n\zeta_1+\sum_{k=1}^n\zeta_{k+1}} \right)\right\|^2\\ \ \\
&=\frac{n^2+n}{{2n}}\geq\frac{n}2
\end{align}