# A system of equations

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a non-separable Hilbert space. Assume $E$ is an orthonormal basis in $H$. Let $E_0=\{e_n\}$ be a countable subset of $E$ and let $\{\zeta_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in $H$. Let $E_1$ be a countable susbet of $E$ and denote $p$ by the projection onto $\overline{span\{e: e\in E_1\}}$.

Question: It seems that, there exists an operator $x\in p^{\perp}B(H)$ satisfying in equations $xe_n=\zeta_n$ for $n=1,2,3,...$, does not it?

Comment: Please make the title more descriptive. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Babak, I did not get what you mean, hopefully this helps: the space $p^{\perp}B(H)$ consists all matrices in the form of $$p^{\perp}B(H)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 &0 \\ 0 &1\end{array}\right)B(H)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 &0 \\ * &*\end{array}\right)$$ where $p=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 &0 \\ 0 &0\end{array}\right)$

Comment: Salam. manzuram in bud ke title re daghightar benewis bara ina. ina gijan. :-)

Comment: Salam, dar morde title shoma kamelan dorost migi,  vali rastesh chizi be nazaram naresid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An obvious necessary condition is that each $\zeta_n$ is in the span of $E_1$. But, in any case, the operator cannot exist in general: just by constructing a counterexample as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1568904/22857).